# How to remove redirect parameter from OAuth2 request?

Tags: redirect, spring-security, oauth, parameters

Using Spring Security OAuth2, is it possible to remove the redirect parameter during the authentication request?

```
AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails resource = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
```

I tried with:

1. `resource.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(null);`
2. `resource.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri(resource.getPreEstablishedRedirectUri());`

but doesn't work.

I always get:

```
http://example.it/oauth/auth?client_id=123456&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/client/&response_type=code&state=123456
```

I want this:

```
http://example.it/oauth/auth?client_id=123456&response_type=code&state=123456
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```java
resource.setUseCurrentUri(false);
```

in this way the HTTP request omits the redirect parameter and redirects to the implicit URI in the server REST.